# Chrome Dev Tools stops at breakpoint even when breakpoints are deactivated

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I encountered an issue while debugging Javascript in the Dev Tools in Chrome.

Even when I have deactivated the breakpoints from the button, it still stops at them.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90ym.png)

I haven't enabled the "Pause on exceptions" button and the only thing that works is when I disable the breakpoints one by one (not having 'tick' on them).
[disabled breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3dj2.png)

I noticed that this appeared in a week or so.

My browser is Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: The issue is gone now, with the last update from chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I had another browser tab open on the same domain and the dev tool was open in that other tab too.
in that case you need to deactive the debugger in both tabs or better yet close the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

> Close inspect element on other tabs of the same domain